# Performance when changing elements

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am working on an application that shows four charts at the same time. The user also has the option to maximize one chart. I am doing this with `.Show()` and `.Hide()` plus changing the column/row span of the underlying table.

E.g.

```
panel2.Hide();
panel3.Hide();
panel4.Hide();

tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(panel1, 2);
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(panel1, 2);
tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(panel1, 0);
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(panel1, 0);
```

Four charts

[image]

One chart

[image]

It works, but the performance is pretty bad. It takes a few seconds to redraw the elements properly and it looks shaky.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use a performance profiler. Always!

Comment: It shows me that changing the font and the .Show method take the longest when I minimize/maximize a chart. I was wondering if there is a better way in general to do this (like moving to the background instead of hiding).